# excel last / max value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to return the last payment and date for payments being made.

Here is some example data

```
A     B           C
desc  date        payment 
0001  12/01/2014  52.00
0002  20/01/2014  56.76
0003  22/01/2014  44.23
0001  12/02/2014  52.00
0002  20/02/2014  56.76
0003  22/02/2014  44.23
0001  11/03/2014  52.00
0002  20/03/2014  56.76
0003  25/03/2014  44.23
0001  12/04/2014  52.00
0002  20/04/2014  56.76
0003  22/04/2014  44.23
0004  10/05/2014  53.05
0002  20/05/2014  56.76
0003  23/05/2014  47.23


These would be the rows returned.


0001  12/04/2014  52.00
0004  10/05/2014  53.05
0002  20/05/2014  56.76
0003  23/05/2014  47.23
```

I've look at some other posts which show this formula that would return the last date but i can't seem to get it to work.

```
{=MAX(IF(AND($A$1:$A$7="0001",$B$1:$B$7<=date(2014,12,31),$B$1:$B$7>=date(2014,1,1)),$B$1:$B$7))}
```

do i need the '{' '}' brackets around my formula ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need brackets around the formula as you are looking in an array. However I believe Excel does this for you if your formula is correct.

Based on your data, you can achieve what you want using the following:

Assuming your data is `A2:C16` as your test data provided is.

Create a lookup based on the `DESC` column, in this instance I have put `0001` into Cell `E2`

For the Date column enter the following into Cell `F2`

`=MAX(IF($A$2:$B$16=$E2,$B$2:$B$16))` Once you have pasted the formula press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` this will add the brackets around the formula, it should also return the `12/04/2014` that you are looking for.

You can obviously replace `$A$2:$B$16=$E2` with `$A$2:$B$16="0001"` if you would prefer.

You can then use an `Index` `Match` to find the Payment Amount:

`=INDEX(C2:C16,MATCH(1,(A2:A16=E2)*(B2:B16=F2),0))`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, I've never used the ctrl+shift+enter before